# loading images from plist

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, plist

I am loading the images from a server like this...

```
- (id)init {
self = [ super init ];
if (self != nil) {
    covers = [ [ NSMutableArray alloc ] init ];

    for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        NSLog(@"Loading demo image %d\n", i);
        UIImage *image = [ [ UIImage alloc ] initWithData:
                          [ NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                           [ NSURL URLWithString: [ NSString stringWithFormat:
                                                   @"http://www.xyz.com/1%d.png", i ] ] ]
                          ];





        [ covers addObject: image ];
    }
}
return self;
```

}

Now i want to load the images from plist file instead of url. Can anyone plz tell me how to do it... Plz help...

Comment: Are you storing the image data, or the image names in the plist file? I highly recommend that you store the image data as a resource in the bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property List can manage NSData and UIImage can be create from NSData:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithData:(NSData *)data
```

But I din't think it is the best way to do this. You can save image file and reference the file in plist.